# React Native Custom Button (include two background, two inner component)

Tags: react-native

How Do I create that Button in React Native?

[image]

As above, button component include two part , left is text part, right part include another background color and image.
But, whole button component includes same border radius and gradient.
Does somebody might know how to get to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap two sibling View components with `TouchableOpacity` component which will handle `onPress` for the whole button. Position them side by side using `flex` and set explicit sizes on each. Left element should get `borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderBottomLeftRadius` and right should get `borderTopRightRadius` and `borderBottomRightRadius`. Border radius is solved separately but it would seem like it's all in one, and for gradient do you mean this inner shadow or something else?

It's because inset shadow does not exist in RN, but it can be faked quite realistically. Read more here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2255.

If you really wan't to use gradient, you must use https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient and position it absolutely over everything and just set it in the background using `zIndex` property.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks.

Comment: But I need gradient , also.

Comment: @BennySudibyo Check the last link in the answer, please.